# How to align tooltip width with the title length?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tooltip, antd

I want the width of the tooltip of antd to be of the same length as that of the title. This is the code

```
<Tooltip placement="top" align={{ offset: [0, 10]  }}
  title='this is the title'>
  <span>tooltip</span>
</Tooltip>
```

Sometimes the width of the tooltip is more than the title width. I am not sure why that is happening. Some times the width of the tooltip is same as the title but at times the tool tip width is more. Why does that happen? What do I do to make the tooltip width the same as title length?
I tried changing resolution to see if was the problem but even then the case repeats. At times the width is same and other time the width is longer than the title length

I don't want to keep the width fixed as I want my web page to be responsive.

Comment: The main css file which was overwriting the width property of the tooltip and hence the issue. It's working now

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to reproduce the problem and it's working fine in the latest antd version. You can take a look at my sandbox to make sure that you update your antd version to the latest:

https://codesandbox.io/s/tooltip-issue-fix-fnmnin?file=/index.js

Or you can share a sandbox with your issue reproduced.

Comment: I am using 4.6.0 version of antd. Since my other elements of antd use the mentioned version I can't change this version.

Comment: can you please provide your react version also which one are you using ?

Comment: 16.12.0 is my react version

Comment: I had a css file which was overwriting the property of the tooltip. I was able to get it to fit properly. Thank you for taking time to reply!